# Check box event trigger

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a two screens on my application each with same component of map. The layers of the map are stored as two list objects with simple ids of the layers representing the visible layers on each screen

```
                <CheckBox 
                    VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                    Margin="3" 
                    IsChecked="{Binding Visible}"
                    ToolTip="Layer visibility"
                    Checked="Visible_Changed"
                    Unchecked="Visible_Changed"
                    />
```

As the user navigates between the two screens the visible property of the layer gets triggered from code behind and the checkbox reflects the same. The layers behave as they should as well.

The problem is that now the user may select one of the layers on any screen as change the visible property of the layer, in which case I have to update the layer list of that screen.

Is there any way I can make the checkbox not trigger the event when the visible property is changed by the code. I only want the event to trigger when user checks the check box

Comment: Just put a barrier around the changed code, like `codeChangedMe = true` when in the event check if it's true and exit

Comment: You can prevent the functionality of the checked event by adding a condition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you can't stop the event from being fired, you can encapsulate the code in the handler with a check for a `bool` flag, which you set to `true` when manually calling the code:

```
<CheckBox Checked="CheckBoxChanged" Unchecked="CheckBoxChanged" />
```

...

```
private void CheckBoxChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!isNotLocalChange)
    {
        // the user changed the Checked value
    }
}
```

elsewhere...

```
isNotLocalChange = true;
// Do your programmatic change here
isNotLocalChange = false;
```